# Converting EditText Value to int

Tags: java

My program sets a numeric value to an editText field..I am trying to convert the edittext values to an integer..I have failed in all the attempts i have tried..Here is how the editText field receives the value:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);

                        totalAmount[0] += dogExpenditure.getAmount();
                        textView3.setText(Integer.toString(totalAmount[0] ));

                    }
                }
```

**textView3.setText(Integer.toString(totalAmount[0]** I am doing this because the **totalAmount[0]** cannot be accessed anywhere else other than inside that program so i decided to pull it from the editText(not sure about this) though i havent succeeded. i get **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""** error:
Here is how i tried :

```
String diff = String.valueOf(textView3.getText());

        Integer x = Integer.valueOf(diff);
        String saley = String.valueOf(textView5.getText());
        Integer v = Integer.valueOf(saley);
```

NB: the **textView5** and **textView5** are both EditText fields..

Comment: Just an hint, `EditText` -> `String` -> `int`. Now, you need to know what String actually represent a Number, as the Exception told you. `""` is not equivalent to `0`

Answer (score 1):

A `NumberFormatException` tell you the String is not a number.

Here, the String is empty so this can't be parse. A solution would be to check for that specific value, like [Jesse Hoobergs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43517914/4391450).

But this will not prevent an exception if I input `foobar`. So the safer solution is to catch the exception. I let you find the correct solution to manager the value if this is not a numerical value.

```
Integer number;
try{
    number = Integer.valueOf(s);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    number = null; //Just an example of default value
    // If you don't manage it with a default value, you need to throw an exception to stop here.
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

At startup, the value of the editText seems to be an empty string ("").
I think you can best check for empty strings or make sure the initial value isn't an empty string.

```
String diff = String.valueOf(textView3.getText());
Integer x = null;
if(!diff.trim().isEmpty())
    x = Integer.valueOf(diff);
```

Comment: I would say, to save on space, maybe just declare `x` and not instantiate it as `null`, but instead add an `else` condition that sets `x` to `null`

Comment: At least use `String.equals()` to do correct comparaison. But `String.isEmpty()` is fine to. Best would be `String.trim().isEmpty()`. And to catch the remaining exception for not numerical String.

Comment: It's just an example, the place where x is best declared depends on the rest of the code, maybe it isn't needed outside the if body or other conditions. If you set the string yourself to an integer, then catching the exception might not be needed, if the user can edit it, than it would be best indeed.

Answer (score 0):

an example that may help you

```
boolean validInput = true;
String theString = String.valueOf(textView3.getText());
  if (!theString.isEmpty()){ // if there is an input
        for(int i = 0; i < theString.length(); i++){ // check for any non-digit
            char c = theString.charAt(i);
            if((c<48 || c>57)){ // if any non-digit found (ASCII chars values for [0-9] are [48-57]
                validInput=false;
            }
        }
  }
  else {validInput=false;}

    if (validInput){// if the input consists of integers only and it's not empty
        int x = Integer.parseInt(theString); // it's safe, take the input
            // do some work
    }
```

Comment: Careful, this work for "our" Local, you should use [`Character.isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) to be more generic. And you could simply use a `for(char c : theString.toCharArray()){...}` ;)

Comment: exactly , that's why I mentioned "ASCII".

Comment: Indeed ! Didn't notice this

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out a better way to deal with this..On startup the values are null..so i created another method that handles the edittext fields with a button  click after the activity has been initialised..and it works..

```
private void diffe() {
        String theString = String.valueOf(textView3.getText().toString().trim());
        String theStringe = String.valueOf(textView5.getText().toString().trim());
        int e = Integer.valueOf(theString);
        int s = Integer.valueOf(theStringe);
        int p = s - e ;
        textView2.setText(Integer.toString(p));
    }
```